# How to block external requests to a NextJS Api route

Tags: django, next.js

I am using NextJS API routes to basically just proxy a custom API built with Python and Django that has not yet been made completely public, I used the tutorial on Vercel to add cors as a middleware to the route however it hasn't provided the exact functionality I wanted.

I do not want to allow any person to make a request to the route, this sort of defeats the purpose for but it still at least hides my API key.

###### Question

Is there a better way of properly stopping requests made to the route from external sources?
Any answer is appreciated!

```js
// Api Route
import axios from "axios";
import Cors from 'cors'

// Initializing the cors middleware
const cors = Cors({
  methods: ['GET', 'HEAD'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization','Origin'],
  origin: ["https://squadkitresearch.net", 'http://localhost:3000'],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
})

function runMiddleware(req, res, fn) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(req, res, (res) => {
      if (res instanceof Error) {
        return reject(res)
      }

      return resolve(res)
    })
  })
}

async function getApi(req, res) {
  try {
    await runMiddleware(req, res, cors)

    const {
      query: { url },
    } = req;
      const URL = `https://xxx/api/${url}`;
      const response = await axios.get(URL, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Api-Key xxxx`,
              Accept: "application/json",
          }
      });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        res.status(200).send(response.data)
      }
      console.log('Server Side response.data -->', response.data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error -->', error)
      res.status(500).send({ error: 'Server Error' });
    }
}

export default getApi
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for this late answer,

I just think that this is the default behaviour of NextJS. You are already set, don't worry. There is in contrast, a little bit customization to make if you want to allow external sources fetching your Next API